# PHP Regex String Exctraction

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP array with 1000s of values, but I want to loop through it and identify the ones with the following pattern.

1234567-xxxx

That is 7 digits and a dash at 8th.

Sample array as below.

```
$a = array(1,1234567-xxx,'Hello','World',2223339-445566,'2)
```

Comment: a pattern OR a literal string ? Elaborate your question and show the expected result

Comment: I just need to identify when this pattern appears in the loop, that is: 7 digits and a dash at 8th. So it is not a string match, it is a pattern match.

Comment: Then use `preg_replace('~^(\d{7})-~', '$1', $a)` if you need to remove that hyphen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably no need to loop. You can use

> [**preg_grep**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) — Return array entries that match the pattern

```
$res = preg_grep('/^\d{7}-/', $a);
```

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/780619) and [regex explained at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6ZlQpG/1)

Comment: Thank you, you are close. Actually do not want to just extract values, I want to loop through the values and when the pattern is found in the loop, I want to do some action on it.

Comment: [`foreach(array_keys(preg_grep('/^\d{7}-/', $a)) AS $k) { /* do something with $a[$k] */ }`](https://eval.in/780646) @phpMax